# ASP.NET 4.5 Authentication Redirect Not Working When Deployed on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, iis, webforms

I built an ASP.NET webforms application for a client, and used Forms authentication for security.  When I run it locally (on three different PCs, plus one of my teammates PCs) we can log in without an issue.  But when we deployed it on the client's server, the log in redirect fails.

We can see that the authentication is working, because the master page updates and shows options that only available to authenticated users, but the form always redirects to the login page.

Here is part of the web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="default.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" defaultUrl="home.aspx" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="60">
        </forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="*" />
        <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
```

The code from the master page that works:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        hylHome.Visible = false;
        hylSearch.Visible = false;
        lbtnLogout.Visible = false;
    }
    else
```

And, just in case, the line that handles creates the authentication:

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtusername.Text, false);

I'm assuming that it is a setting on the IIS server somewhere that is stopping the redirect, but I have no knowledge of servers.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: What exactly fails during the logging in?

Comment: While it may not answer this question, I'm pretty sure you want `<deny users="?" />`

Comment: Have you tried placing DestinationPageUrl="yourpage.aspx" within your login control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two updates fixed the issue.  As Darren Kopp pointed out, the web.config had to be updated to:

`<deny users="?" />`

After that, I was also missing a `response.redirect="default.aspx"` at the end of the authentication method, inspired by Humpy's comment.